# Where is the right place to ask for source of ready traffic camera video?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I don't know where is the right place to ask for some free source of ready traffic camera video to download. I need these videos to test some object recognition prototype.

Comment: Pretty much off-topic everywhere I would imagine - "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic."

Comment: Is it another place to ask?

Comment: Google would seem to be a good place .... try searching for "traffic camera video" ...

Comment: And then search for "how do i download streaming video"